# How to format numbers in C# MVC 4 to reflect a two decimal point currency?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formatting

So I'm having trouble with my view wanting more numbers behind the decimal point as input than I want it to need.

I am using this model:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

This is in my view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model =>  model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
```

It seem that simply adding the DisplayFormat attribute to Movie.Price isn't enough to allow users to enter numbers like 2,79, if they try they'll get the validation error. The input field created by @Html.EditorFor(model =>  model.Price) instead requires the number to be 2,790 (notice the additional 0 added behind the decimal).

I've tried a variety of DataFormatStrings but all to no effect, what am I missing/not understanding?

How do I adjust my code so users are able to enter 2,79 as a valid input instead of 2,790?

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* the server is using the right culture? It looks like it's trying to interpret the `,` as a thousands separator and not a decimal point. Also is the validation error happening client-side or server-side?

Comment: @Ic No I am not, how would I go about changing the culture, which btw is a new concept to me. I suppose it happens client side since the validation error part happens in the browser..

Comment: The client-side validation may be more difficult, but you can start looking at the validation rules (attributes of the input element if you're using unobtrusive validation) and associated JavaScript. As far as server-side you can [globally set a value in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`  /`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in the controller if you want to do this dynamically or per-page. Someone can probably provide a more complete answer though.

Comment: @Ic I assume culture has somethings to do with culture-specific settings, which can ofcourse potentially fix the problem. However I don't need the input to be interpreted as a currency perse, I need it to be interpreted as a number with with two numbers behind the decimal point.

Comment: Yes but the problem here is in the default culture, the decimal point is `.` and not `,` (i.e. `1234 + 56/100` is represented `1,234.56` and not `1.234,56`). You need to set the proper culture so parsing works correctly in your format.

Comment: @Ic That was the missing piece of the puzzle, thank you. Could you create an answer so I can accept it and you can claim your just reward? :)

Comment: I was hoping someone could create a more detailed answer but sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the server - and most likely client-side validation scripts too - is parsing a comma (`,`) not as a decimal separator, but as a thousands separator. This is because, in the default culture, the decimal point is `.`. So 1234 + 56/100 is "normally" represented as `1,234.56` and not `1.234,56`.

You need to set the proper culture so parsing works correctly in your format. Do this by either [globally setting a value in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or manually setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` / `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` from the controller if you need more fine-grained control.

This will also most likely *not* bubble down to client-side validation, so you will need to make sure you write the proper JavaScript validation rules as well to override the default ones.

---

As a side note, you may want to do something to indicate to your users which format to expect. People from other parts of the world write numbers differently, and might expect things to be in their native format. (Sometimes the language of the page is a good hint of the expected number/date formats though.)